# set extent for jpeg programmatically

Tags: arcpy, raster, coordinates, python-2.7, python-addin

I feel like this should be easy, but how can I set coordinates for a jpeg image using Python?  I have a python add-in that draws a polygon and then uses its geometry to post a query request to a REST endpoint for an Image Service.  The JSON return is a .jpg image.

I am able to download the image no problem, but obviously it is not georeferenced because it is just an image.  The JSON return does give me the extent of the photo though (UTM 15N).  How can I set this extent to be that of the image?  I thought about making a [world file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t00000028000000), but this does not use the extent of a raster.

Here is the JSON return, how can I apply that extent to the downloaded image?

[image]

I have looked all over the help docs and cannot find where I can set an extent manually.  I was hoping that the arcpy.Raster() class would allow me to set the extent, but that property is read only.  Am I missing something obvious?  Seems like this should be easy.

Comment: With "define projection" you can at least set the CRS...
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000077000000 ...plus maybe some shift? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Shift/00170000007t000000/

Comment: Right, I am able to set the projection and I even tried to run the convert raster to other format tool with an output extent environment set to the extent shown in the picture above. No dice.  I should also add that these services do not support rendering/raster functions so I cannot use the Clip shown here:  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r3000000rv000000

Comment: Where does your raster show up in the resulting Arcgis document? At coordinates 0,0?

Comment: Yes, the coordinates come in at 0,0.

Comment: Then use shift ( http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Shift/00170000007t000000/ ) to shift your raster to the desired position.

Comment: That almost worked...Unfortunately, the returned images from the REST API do not seem to match the extent that is returned with the image.  I tried to shift by the upper left corner (xMin, yMax) and it is off by about 35 meters on the y-axis.

Comment: Would you be able to include a code snippet that illustrates where you are currently stuck?

Comment: I gave up on this long ago, but maybe the script I was using was similar to my answer on [Arcpy/REST: how to save raster dataset from URL](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166462/arcpy-rest-how-to-save-raster-dataset-from-url?noredirect=1&lq=1)