# Loading JSON with image link and extents into ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, json, arcgis-rest-api

One of the ways to get data from ArcGIS REST API in image format is this.

```
https://services.twdb.texas.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Base/BaseLayerQueryService/MapServer/export?bbox=-11360770.018835%2C3942451.651995%2C-11357251.989618%2C3945703.856100&bboxSR=&layers=show%3A8&layerDefs=&size=847%2C783&imageSR=&format=png&transparent=true&dpi=&time=&layerTimeOptions=&dynamicLayers=&gdbVersion=&mapScale=&rotation=&datumTransformations=&layerParameterValues=&mapRangeValues=&layerRangeValues=&f=json
```

The return is a JSON like this

```
{
 "href": "https://services.twdb.texas.gov/arcgis/rest/directories/arcgisoutput/Base/BaseLayerQueryService_MapServer/_ags_mape38a2c53b769401a86d7d8f1751fc8a2.png",
 "width": 847,
 "height": 783,
 "extent": {
  "xmin": -11360770.018835019,
  "ymin": 3942451.651995,
  "xmax": -11357251.989617988,
  "ymax": 3945703.8561,
  "spatialReference": {
   "wkid": 102100,
   "latestWkid": 3857
  }
 },
 "scale": 15698.301990971015
}
```

If I save this as a file, is there a way to load this in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: One option is to use scripting, via `arcpy`, have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166462/arcpy-rest-how-to-save-raster-dataset-from-url. The hyperlinked PNG lives in a while on the server and then gets deleted due by its expiry. If you are to follow manual processing path, after saving the imagery, you can **georeference** it by using `extent` parameter values in the JSON. Make sure you are using the right coordinate system, for this instance, https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/epsg3857-wgs84-web-mercator-auxiliary-sphere/